# I need help in this error "TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, scikit-learn, data-science

My code is:

```
escolaridade = dados4[dados4["DMDEDUC"] == 5]
sentimento = dados4[dados4["DPQ020"] != 0].head(875)
plt.bar(escolaridade,sentimento, color="blue")
plt.xlabel("Superior Completo")
plt.ylabel("Deprimido 1x na semana")
plt.tittle("Relação da tristeza com um adulto graduado")
plt.show()
```

I defined the `.head(875)` because the length of `escolaridade` and `sentimento` are distinct.

"DMDEDUC" and "DPQ020" are numerical columns of a dataframe and for this I didn't understand the error.

> "TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Thanks!

Comment: you are passing a whole dataframe for both the x and the y array arguments
only pass columns:
`plt.bar(df['A'],df['B'], color="blue")`

Comment: Your code is missing reproducible test data.  Even more pressing is a lack of explanation of what you want to visualize.  It is very strange that you are capping the length of one of the columns.  Does that mean they don't have a common index? Also note that 875 values are too many to nicely show in a bar plot.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to make a plot is `plt.bar(x, y)`, where x is an array of x-coordinates, and y is an array of y-coordinates. In your code you seem to extract the coordinates based on different conditions: (DMDEDUC == 5) and (DPQ020 != 0). Will the final set of (x,y) coordinates still make sense?

If it is feasible, try this code:

```
n = 875    #specify the number of rows
escolaridade = dados4.loc[dados4["DMDEDUC"] == 5].head(n)
x = escolaridade["DMDEDUC"]
sentimento = dados4.loc[dados4["DPQ020"] != 0].head(n)
y = sentimento["DPQ020"]
plt.bar(x, y, color="blue")
plt.xlabel("Superior Completo")
plt.ylabel("Deprimido 1x na semana")
plt.tittle("Relação da tristeza com um adulto graduado")
plt.show()
```

If I understand correctly to maintain the relationship between x and y, try below code:

```
df = dados4.loc[(dados4["DMDEDUC"] == 5) and (dados4["DPQ020"] != 0)]
escolaridade = df["DMDEDUC"]
sentimento = df["DPQ020"]
plt.bar(escolaridade, sentimento, color="blue")
plt.xlabel("Superior Completo")
plt.ylabel("Deprimido 1x na semana")
plt.tittle("Relação da tristeza com um adulto graduado")
plt.show()
```

Hope the above helps! Please let me know, cheers!